# Failed to execute 'openDatabase' on 'Window': Access to the WebDatabase API is denied in non-secure contexts

Tags: javascript, http, web-sql

Error: Unknown error SecurityError: Failed to execute 'openDatabase' on 'Window': Access to the WebDatabase API is denied in non-secure contexts..

Code javascript:
`window.openDatabase('teste.db', '1.0', '', 2000 * 1024 * 1024);`

Expecting: Database {version: '1.0'}

Chrome version 110, failed in HTTP remote address, have solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:
https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#WebSQLNonSecureContextEnabled

WebSQL in non-secure contexts will be removed starting M110. This policy re-enables the API. If this policy is set to true, WebSQL in non-secure contexts will be available. If this policy is set to false or unset, WebSQL in non-secure contexts will remain available until M109, then unavailable starting M110. This was removed in M112.